# What proportion of the positive integers satisfies $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))>\sigma(n)$, where $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

The title says it all.

> What proportion of the positive integers satisfies $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))>\sigma(n)$, where $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function?

I tried using [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to search for positive integers $n$ satisfying the said inequality, in the range $1 \leq n \leq {10}^6$, but it was unable to find any.

I dare to conjecture that the proportion in question is zero, but I have no proof.

**Updated November 28 2018**

I got the same output as Julian, after running the following (presumably correct) GP code in Sage Cell Server:

```
for (x=1, 1000000,if(gcd(x^2,sigma(x^2))>sigma(x),print(x)))
```

**Updated November 29 2018**

The number $n=1$ satisfies
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\sigma(n)$$
while almost all integers $n>1$ (except for the $111$ numbers less than ${10}^6$ mentioned by Julian in his answer below) satisfy
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))<\sigma(n).$$

Therefore, I think it might indeed be possible to prove that the set
$$\bigg\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) > \sigma(n)\bigg\}$$
has asymptotic density $0$.  But then again, as I have already mentioned, I have no proof.

Comment: Note that $n$ must be composite.

Comment: There are $111$ integers below $10^6$ satisfying the inequality. The smallest is $693$.

Comment: Blimey! @Julian, please write out your comment as an actual answer so that I may be able to accept it.

Comment: How often does it happen that $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\gt1$?

Comment: @BarryCipra, very often, I must say!  Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mathematica I found that there are $111$ integers below $10^6$ satisfying the inequality. They are

\begin{align}
&693, 1386, 1463, 1881, 2379, 2926, 4389, 4758, 8778, 9516, 11895, \\
&13167, 16653, 18018, 19032, 23790, 24180, 25641, 26169, 26334, 33306, \\
&37271, 40443, 43890, 45201, 52668, 54717, 57057, 61380, 65835, 73150, \\
&78507, 105336, 109725, 111813, 114114, 131670, 157014, 166530, \\
&169959, 171171, 183183, 185801, 210672, 214830, 218085, 219450, \\
&223626, 223839, 230763, 233142, 238887, 250173, 263340, 291555, \\
&294996, 302841, 316407, 329175, 342342, 366366, 368745, 371602, \\
&380737, 381843, 392535, 405384, 408177, 421344, 429660, 447252, \\
&447678, 461526, 477774, 487179, 497211, 500346, 526680, 530439, \\
&539847, 549549, 557403, 559065, 566181, 570570, 605682, 611403, \\
&615660, 618849, 632814, 637032, 658350, 684684, 692289, 697851, \\
&737490, 763686, 766038, 776853, 782691, 803187, 809424, 816354, \\
&855855, 882189, 894504, 901641, 923052, 934857, 961191, 974358
\end{align}
The sequence is now in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A322154).

Code:

```
Select[Range[10^6], GCD[#^2, DivisorSigma[1, #^2]] > DivisorSigma[1, #] &]
```

Comment: The sequence has been submitted to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A322154) and is currently pending for review.

Comment: [OEIS sequence A322154](http://oeis.org/A322154) has already been approved.